# How to change size of UIButton if it is a certain size

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, uibutton, sender

I have looked at and tried many things but cannot find a way that will. What I am trying to do is create an if statement in my code that states that if one of the sender(a UIButton)'s dimensions, either height or width, are below 50, they would become a 50 x 50 UIButton equal to a randomColor() and randomPoint(). Thank you. Below is my code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

    var points: Int = 0

    func randomPoint() -> CGPoint {
        let randomPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x:CGFloat(arc4random()%320),y:CGFloat(arc4random()%568))
        return randomPoint
    }

    func randomColor() -> UIColor {
        let red = CGFloat(drand48())
        let green = CGFloat(drand48())
        let blue = CGFloat(drand48())
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    func spawnEnemy() {
        let enemy: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 160, y: 160, width: 150, height: 150))
        enemy.backgroundColor = randomColor()
        enemy.center = randomPoint()
        enemy.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonPushed:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(enemy)
    }

    func buttonPushed(sender : UIButton) {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        points = points + 1
        scoreLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        scoreLabel.text = "\(points)"
        scoreLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.75, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnEnemy"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

}
```

I have updated my code but I still do not think it is working. I think it is because a lot of the time the squares are left as "L"s after a full overlapping square is clicked and you are left with an "L". Any way to fix this and make it so if will always work. My code is below in case it is actually or also something else?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

    var points: Int = 0

    func randomPoint() -> CGPoint {
        let randomPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x:CGFloat(arc4random()%320),y:CGFloat(arc4random()%568))
        return randomPoint
    }

    func randomColor() -> UIColor {
        let red = CGFloat(drand48())
        let green = CGFloat(drand48())
        let blue = CGFloat(drand48())
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    func spawnEnemy() {
        let enemy: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 160, y: 160, width: 150, height: 150))
        enemy.backgroundColor = randomColor()
        enemy.center = randomPoint()
        enemy.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonPushed:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(enemy)
    }

    func buttonPushed(sender : UIButton) {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        points = points + 1
        scoreLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        scoreLabel.text = "\(points)"
        scoreLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        if sender.frame.height < 50 || sender.frame.width < 50 {
            sender.frame = CGRectMake(sender.frame.origin.x, sender.frame.origin.y, 50, 50)
            sender.backgroundColor = self.randomColor()
            sender.center = self.randomPoint()
            return
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.75, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnEnemy"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

}
```

Comment: You want this check to happen after the user pushes the button? I'm just looking for clarification on what triggers this check.

Comment: So what happens is that once you build the application 150 x 150 squares randomly spawn every 3/4 of a second. But once a square spawns over another non-clicked square, it is overlapping, so once you click the top square and it turns back(like backgroundColor), unless the squares were perfectly overlapping there can be small spots left that are hard to click and i am trying to fix that without totally destroying them, just recreating them as a 50 x 50 UIButton that can have the same thing done to them(spawning randomly and being able to be clicked and turned black). I hope that helps a little.

Comment: I'm not following 100%, but hopefully my answer helps a little.  This will make it so that all buttons clicked get evaluated to see if it's smaller than 50x50, and if it is it will become 50x50, a new color, and it'll move somewhere random.

Comment: Ya, reading over the code it should definitely work but what would happen if it is an "L" that has two 150 sides(150 x 150) but then the height of one and width of other rectangle is like 5... it stays I think. How could that fixed?

Comment: That || means that it'll see if the height OR the width is less than 50 - they don't both need to be true for it to pass the check.  So if any side is less than 50 it'll change it to 50x50, new color, new location.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to make this check after the user pushes the button, you can add a check inside your `buttonPressed:` function like this:

```
func buttonPushed(sender : UIButton) {
    if sender.frame.height < 50 || sender.frame.width < 50 {
        sender.frame = CGRectMake(sender.frame.origin.x, sender.frame.origin.y, 50, 50)
        sender.backgroundColor = self.randomColor()
        sender.center = self.randomPoint()
        return
    }
    sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    points = points + 1
    scoreLabel.textAlignment = .Center
    scoreLabel.text = "\(points)"
    scoreLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

This will see if the height or width is less than 50 points, and if it is it'll set the size to 50x50, set it to a random color, and set the center to the random point.  It'll be an instant jump, though, so if you want to animate that you can do that instead.  The `return` part will just ensure the rest of the code below doesn't get executed.

Comment: By the way, i notice it does not trigger and compiler errors, but why did you have an empty return at the end? What does it do?

Comment: return will make it so that nothing below the code gets executed, and it will essentially stop the execution of the function immediately.  It's very useful in cases like this where you want to do some kind of check and depending on the outcome execute different blocks of code.  In this specific case it just prevents the 5 lines at the bottom of your function from being executed.

Comment: If you take the return out it will change the size to 50x50, set the bg color, move it to a random point, and then keep going - set the bg color to black, increment the points, do the stuff with scoreLabel.  If any of that stuff still needs to happen you either need to copy it and put it before the return, or add an else clause to handle the stuff that happens only when the button is bigger than 50x50, and put the common code outside of the if/else blocks.  I hope this makes sense.  I'll totally help out if you're trying to do something like this.

Comment: Also, in the code block above that I have included in my code(  inside the buttonPressed() func  ) , the if statement is referring to the sender, or the button that is clicked. But why would you do it after the button has been clicked? Is there a way to do that without having to click it. Now realizing that, I do not see how that would work, if it sees after it has been clicked after t here is nothing there.???

Comment: I guess I just don't understand what point in your application you want to check the size of the buttons.  I assumed you wanted to check after a specific button was clicked on because you used the term "sender" in your question, implying that it's the button "sending a message", or (in other words) triggering a function.  Tell me exactly where in your application you need to check the size of the button.